# how to add value to duration attribute in drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-flow, drools-kie-server

Whenever i write duration(0s), it works but as soon as i change it to duration(1s) or duration(5s), the rule doesn't fire... 
This is the rule which i want to fire.

```
rule "ContainsChecking"

agenda-group "town4"

duration(0s)

when

Town(owner matches "[N || n][a-z]+")

then

System.out.println("Rule Fired ContainsChecking");

end
```

do we need to import something for duration attribute to work, because i m not getting it anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the session using

```
kieSession.fireUntilHalt();
```

If you just use fireAllRules, the agenda is empty and the call terminates.

This is a CEP feature and need not and should not be used in a simple production rule environment.

Comment: as i am adding this kieSession.fireUntilHalt(); into @test case.. it is throwing error that kiesession cannot be resolved. So what should i do. Thanks.

Comment: Use the identifier for the object reference with which you have called fireAllRules. (How am I to know such details of your program?)